# VB6: console get mouse position reading input buffer events

Tags: events, input, vb6, console, buffer

Can anyone help me with writing code in VB6 that reads input buffer events from a console window?
The most important part is the mouse cursor position in cells and rows.

I am making a program in VB6 that uses a console as the main gui (or should I say cui) and I can't find an example in vb code that uses 'Input Buffer Events'.

This example code does exactly what I want but it's in c++ and i'm using VB6:
    https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685035(v=vs.85).aspx

I have a lot of trouble converting the code because I don't know much about c++.
Here are some other links that already gave me some idea of how to start:

- http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/10926_1538861_6/Writing-Console-Mode-Applications-in-Visual-Basic.htm
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/10/14/how-to-create-a-vb6-console-program/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/06/10416225.aspx
- http://microsoft.public.vb.winapi.narkive.com/avYXhXUG/readconsoleinput-and-input-record
- http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleInput.html

Here is my module, its all I have:

```
Private Const ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT = &H10
Private Const ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = &H8
Private Const ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS = &H80

Private Const STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10&
Private Const STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11&

Private Const MOUSE_MOVED = &H1

Private Type COORD
    x As Integer
    y As Integer
End Type

Private Type SMALL_RECT
    Left As Integer
    Top As Integer
    Right As Integer
    Bottom As Integer
End Type

Type INPUT_RECORD
    iEventType As Integer
    abData(0 To 15) As Byte
End Type

Private Type CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
    dwSize As COORD
    dwCursorPosition As COORD
    wAttributes As Integer
    srWindow As SMALL_RECT
    dwMaximumWindowSize As COORD
End Type

Type KEY_EVENT_RECORD
    lKeyDown As Long
    iRepeatCount As Integer
    iVirtualKeyCode As Integer
    iVirtualScanCode As Integer
    iChar As Integer
    lControlKeyState As Long
End Type

Type MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD
    CDMOUSEPOSITION As COORD
    lButtonState As Long
    lControlKeyState As Long
    lEventFlags As Long
End Type

Type FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD
    lSetFocus As Long
End Type

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDestination As Any, pSource As Any, ByVal lByteCount As Long)

Private Declare Function AllocConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetStdHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal nStdHandle As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SetConsoleMode Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hConsoleOutput As Long, dwMode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadConsoleInput Lib "kernel32" Alias "ReadConsoleInputA" (ByVal hConsoleInput As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nLength As Long, lpNumberOfEventsRead As Long) As Long

'##################################################################################################

Private Sub Main()
    AllocConsole

        Dim hConsoleIn As Long
        Dim hConsoleOut As Long

        Dim IR As INPUT_RECORD
        Dim MER As MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD
        Dim ret As Long

        hConsoleIn = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
        hConsoleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)

        Call SetConsoleMode(hConsoleOut, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT Or ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT Or ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS)

        Dim x As Long
        Dim y As Long

        Do
            ReadConsoleInput hConsoleIn, MER, 1, ret

            Select Case IR.iEventType
                Case MOUSE_EVENT
                    Call CopyMemory(MER, IR.abData(0), Len(MER))
                    x = MER.CDMOUSEPOSITION.x
                    y = MER.CDMOUSEPOSITION.y

                    If MsgBox(x & "|" & y, vbOKCancel) = vbCancel Then Exit Do
            End Select

        Loop

    FreeConsole
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me?
Kind regards!

Comment: What are your results with the code posted?

Comment: @jac: Well, the code is not finished because I don't know how to code the rest, I forgot to add the small_rect type. now the console screen appears fine (did edit my code here). This module is a trimmed down version of an other test module where I was writing to the console etc.. can you help me? :)

Comment: I did a new edit in the code trying to get the mouse x and y, I just don't get it, how does this work?

Comment: Well.. this is how every VB6 related topic ends I guess.. Can anyone recommend me a forum that still reply's on VB6 questions?